# Should I use a video sitemap when my video URLs change every two hours to prevent hotlinking?

Tags: google, google-search-console, sitemap, video, lighttpd

I have over 10k videos hosted on my server, and I'm using lighttpd to switch the video URLs every 2 hours because of hotlinking protection. This means that all video URLs in video sitemap is only valid for 2 hours.

I have not much experiences of programming, and this is the source i found:

http://forum.adultscriptpro.com/viewtopic.php?id=588

After reading some comments on this question, It is possible to do that by cronjob to generate new sitemap every 2 hours.

But my another big question is, is it really important to having a video sitemap for a video website? Or i can just submit a normal sitemap.xml instead of the video sitemap?

Any suggestion or advice? Thanks!

Comment: If the URL is frequently changing, sitemaps aren't useful for you.

Comment: hm... If i using CDN or Wowza, can solve this problem?

Comment: How would a CDN solve this problem?

Comment: I don't know. So, which mean video sitemap only for those website with static video URL? And not for website with CDN, wowza, lighttpd..etc? Am i correct?

Comment: If the URLs of your videos keep changing, regardless of source, they aren't good candidates for sitemaps. By the time the search engines read the sitemap those videos are gone. Is there any reason why the video URLs keep changing?

Comment: To prevent leeching.

Comment: Can you explain in your question the reason for changing the URL of the video? It's not a normal circumstance and may be that can be addressed, even when it's not part of the original question. I suppose is not for security or privacy that you change the URl, otherwise, you won't be bothered by not being indexed; but I may be wrong

Comment: Don't bother with a video sitemap then unless you set it to generate a new one via cron job every two hours. But there is little point in all honesty as @JohnConde states.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the comments. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

As [John Conde](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/1253/john-conde) says in the comments:

> If the URLs of your videos keep changing, regardless of source, they aren't good candidates for sitemaps. By the time the search engines read the sitemap those videos are gone.

It sounds like your pages have URLs that are not changing, but your URLs for the video content is changing frequently.   In that case a regular sitemap sounds like an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent leeching, a better method would be to block referrers.

You can set up your server so that the video is only served when it has your site as the 'Referer' header. Or use a blacklist and only block sites as/when they become a problem.

That way your video URLs stay static and you can put them in the sitemap.